# asp form - access database - cyrillic russian results page problem

Tags: forms, ms-access, asp-classic, localization, character-encoding

Inherited problem...  the site works fine in 6 other languages, in fact the Russian area is now working fine and the request quote form work (functionally), with one problem, the email results we get is loaded with very weird letters: (here they are copied)

ôâàïôâàïôâàï
ïôâàïôâàïôâàï
ôâàïôâûàïôêàï
ôêûâï
ïôâàïûâàï

I have tried to encode the form page with everything from windows-1251, utf-8 and kio8, and always the same problem (even viewing the results page on 4 different machine), and as usual with my luck, I have a deadline and out of ideas

Craig

Answer (score 1):

Those are in windows-1251 actually. Decoded, they'd look like:

> фвапфвапфвап пфвапфвапфвап фвапфвыапфкап фкывп пфвапывап

Using UTF-8 as web page encoding should work just fine - it works here on StackOverflow after all ;-) Your form data must be getting corrupted somewhere in your code during processing of form submission.